# How to get access to intent values from static class broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast

Is it possible to start an intent to another activity from `broadcastreceiver` scope?

For example, I get an answer from an intentservice with a string as `putExtra`  value in the broadcast. Now I want to assign this string to a local variable in the activity, which received the broadcast or start an intent from the broadcast scope of the receiving activity to another activity with a `putExtra` containing the received value from the broadcast of the intentservice.

Can anyone tell me, what would be the preferd way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
You can use `intent.getExtras()` in the `onReceive()` callback of your `BroadcastReceiver` to get access to whatever was sent with `putExtra`

You can then build a new `Intent` to start an activity. Don't forget to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag if you are starting the activity from a non-activity context.
You can also copy all the extras from the broadcast:

```
@Override void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String arg = intent.getExtras().getString("the key used in putExtra");
    // do something with the argument

    //or, launch an activity and pass that argument
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    activityIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    context.startActivity(activityIntent);
}
```